# Get a div to take the remaining width but not to make its container bigger when its text overflows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There are many related threads but none of them are helping me find a solution, which may be down to my ineptitude but I don't feel like there's any more research I can do on this.

In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L3dozygq/24/

I am trying to get the "dialogbox" class to be sized according to the main part of the screen, the form, that the red box will contain. The red box is specifically sized with hard coded style=width: etc. We want the title of the dialog to only occupy the space available, and we don't want it to make the dialog wider when there's a large amount of text in there. So the red box determines the width of the entire dialog, and the title should size itself according to that.

I've been trying a flexbox strategy but I would be happy with a flexbox or non-flexbox solution. However I would like to avoid floats.

The two classes we are interested in are the flex container:

```
.dialogheader
```

and the children

```
.dialogheadertitle
.dialogheaderrightside
```

THese are at the top of the css in the fiddle.

You might need to run the fiddle in a new window to prove it works properly- add /show to the URL in a new window to do this.

Comment: I was trying to go through this to come up with a solution to help out but you have tons of conflicting styles that make this very difficult to work with. For example you have elements that you are saying are inline-block elements that are in flex elements, as well inline styles I am not sure if the inline styles on your end are generated by whatever plugin you are using and you copy and pasted it or if thats something you added to the html I would suggest taking sometime to clean up the fiddle a little bit so we can provide better help.

Comment: ok yes I will do that

Comment: ok fiddle is now much simpler - fiddle link is updated in main question - thank you

Comment: The one answer we have so far does not satisfy the requirement to not hardcode the total width of the dialog which is what we need here. Conceputally we need it to autosize based on some of the contents but some of the other contents should then size themselves based on the autosizing already done - how is this possible in HTML/CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

Add these style

```
 div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dialogheadertitle {
      max-width:790px;
  }
  .dialogheader {
    height: auto;
  }
.dialogheader.draggabledialog {
  display: flex !important; 
}
```

Check updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3dozygq/27/)

```css
 
.dialogveil {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  /* for old browsers */
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.7);
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  /* bug in IE needs this see stack overflow 40221351 */
}

.dialogcentre {
  /*  exists only to center the div  */
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dialogbox {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border: 1px solid #111111;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 40px #222222;
  vertical-align: top;
  /* correcting the alignments set from parent div above */
  text-align: left;
}

.dialogheader {
  background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);
  background-color: rgba(239, 239, 239, 1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111111;
  height: 21px;
  cursor: default;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.popover .dialogheader {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

.dialogheadertitle {
  color: #bb2200;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 4px 0px 0px 14px;
  font-size: 9pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.dialogheaderrightside {
  float: right;
  height: 21px;
}

.dialogheadericons {
  width: 47px;
  height: 21px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}

.dialogheaderclose {
  width: 47px;
  height: 21px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: Red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
}

.dialogbody {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  /* all except popup */
}
.dialogcentre {
  position: static;
  display: inline-block;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dialogheadertitle {
  max-width:790px;
  }
  .dialogheader {
height: auto;
  }
.dialogheader.draggabledialog {
  display: flex !important; 
}
```

```html
<div class="dialogveil" style="z-index: 101; display: block;">
  <div class="dialog dialogcentre dragparent" style="position: absolute; left: 12px; top: 27px;">
<div class="dialogbox">
  <div class="dialogheader draggabledialog">

    <!-- THIS DIV SHOULD NOT EXPAND THE DIALOG BOX -->

    <div class="dialogheadertitle">Monitor: Dell P190S Monitor 333 Dell P190S Monitor 333Dell P190S Monitor 333Dell P190S Monitor 333Dell P190S Monitor 333Dell P190S Monitor 333Dell P190S Monitor 333Dell P190S Monitor 333Dell P190S Monitor 333</div>
    <div class="dialogheaderrightside">
      <div class="dialogheadericons"></div>
      <div class="dialogheaderclose" title="Close this Window"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dialogbody">
    <div class="form formeditasset">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div style="width:790px;height:150px;border:2px solid red;">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It still looks like the same problem exists, that the header is forcing the main dialog container to go wider than the form in the body of the dialog. What we want is for the dialog to be sized according the the line surrounding the reference and barcode fields

Comment: i.e. this solution sizes it to 99% of the jsfiddle window or browser window, but what we actually want is it sized to the only element in the form which is deliberately sized: <div id="assetentryform-inner" class="xainner xavtext bind xainnersubform " style="max-width:790px;max-height:550px;">

Comment: thank you. A new fiddle should be up in 30 mins or so

Comment: thanks, but this is still the same problem. We don't want the width to be 100% - we want the width to be enough to contain the red box and no more, and we want the dialog title to size itself according to that width (hiding any excess text)

Comment: It is now updated - please use the fiddle link in the updated question : http://jsfiddle.net/L3dozygq/24/   - we are looking to size the whole dialog to fit around the red box, and the title should not make it bigger than that

Comment: Updated the answer, please check, i may have missed mentioning some styles in the answer above. Please compare your and my styles once to be sure. Thanks

Comment: thanks, I can see that you've hard coded the width to make this work. In reality I was hoping that we could do it without hard coding the width of the dialog, since it would need to be calculated by javascript (the red box might consist of several inline block elements). I was hoping for a responsive solution where the size of the form is dictated by its body contents, and the title of the form (dialog) will simply resize itself according to the size of the form